# Calculate average, variance and standard deviation of two numbers in two different rows/columns with sql / PHP on specific dates

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, date, variance

I have a Database with the following structure:

```
rowid       ID                  startTimestamp   endTimestamp   subject
1           00:50:c2:63:10:1a   ...1000          ...1090        entrance
2           00:50:c2:63:10:1a   ...1100          ...1270        entrance
3           00:50:c2:63:10:1a   ...1300          ...1310        door1
4           00:50:c2:63:10:1a   ...1370          ...1400        entrance
.
.
.
```

With this SQL-Query i can get the average differences between the endTime and the startTime between one row and the following row, sorted by subject and ID, with their min,max,variance and standard deviation:

```
SELECT ID,AVG(diff) AS average,
   AVG(diff*diff) - AVG(diff)*AVG(diff) AS variance,
   SQRT(AVG(diff*diff) - AVG(diff)*AVG(diff)) AS stdev,
   MIN(diff) AS minTime,
   MAX(diff) AS maxTime

FROM
(SELECT t1.id, t1.endTimestamp,
        min(t2.startTimeStamp) - t1.endTimestamp AS diff
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table1 t2
ON t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.subject = t1.subject
AND t2.startTimestamp > t1.startTimestamp  -- consider only later startTimestamps
WHERE t1.subject = 'entrance'
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.endTimestamp) AS diffs
GROUP BY ID
```

This works fine, if i have only a few rows on the same day with less time differences, you can see it in this sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6de73/1

But when i have additional data on just a different day, i get bad values:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/920b6/1

Therefore, I want to calculate the avg, min, max, variance, standard deviation for each single day.

I know that there are the DATE-Functions of MySQL but i couldn't get it done...can somebody help me? Or do i have to write a piece of PHP code that could handle this?

Comment: Given that MySQL has functions for standard deviation and variance, is there a reason not to use them?

Comment: Is that MySQL, or SQLite, or both?

Comment: I would prefer a solution in sqlite...but sqlitefiddle always returns a error if i try to switch...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it as easy as adding the date into the `group by`.  Here is syntax that should work in both MySQL and SQLite, basing the date on the end time and assuming the end time is stored as a datetime:

```
SELECT ID, thedate, AVG(diff) AS average,
   AVG(diff*diff) - AVG(diff)*AVG(diff) AS variance,
   SQRT(AVG(diff*diff) - AVG(diff)*AVG(diff)) AS stdev,
   MIN(diff) AS minTime,
   MAX(diff) AS maxTime
FROM (SELECT t1.id, t1.endTimestamp, DATE(endtimestamp) as thedate,
             min(t2.startTimeStamp) - t1.endTimestamp AS diff
      FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN
           table1 t2
           ON t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.subject = t1.subject AND
              t2.startTimestamp > t1.startTimestamp  -- consider only later startTimestamps
     WHERE t1.subject = 'entrance'
     GROUP BY t1.id, t1.endTimestamp
    ) AS diffs
GROUP BY ID, thedate
```

If stored as a time stamp, see Marty's comment.

Comment: If you use `DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(endtimestamp)) as thedate` it'll work.

Comment: Hi, i have done another Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/920b6/48  It looks pretty nice...i will check the values in the evening and write again...

Comment: There's another Problem: There are some very high values from one day to the other. For example, the value of 9999689 is coming from the difference of the last rowID 4 - rowID 17. Is there the possibility to filter these high values out?

Comment: Is it correct when i just put a AND - clause in: `code` AND t2.startTimeStamp - t1.endTimestamp < 100000    `code`      http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/920b6/55

Comment: @MichaelMeier . . .You probably want to filter out anything that starts on one day and ends on another.  If you know a reasonableness threshold, then just add in a `where` clause like `where diff < 100000` or whatever.

Comment: One last thing: How can i get the amount of differences in a separate column? i have put the definition in the comments: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f1a82/1 The ID's have 3, 3 and 4 Cycles

Comment: @MichaelMeier . . . I don't know what you mean by "amount of differences".  Three ideas as `sum(diff)`, `sum(abs(diff))`, and `count(distinct diff)`.

Comment: There are 3 ID's, and there are 3 numbers (21,30,70) for '00:50:c2:63:10:1a', 4 numbers (30,300,10) for 'xx:50:c2:63:10:2a', 4 numbers (30,10,30,40) for 'yy:50:c2:63:10:2a'.It's `count(distinct diff)`