# How calculate mysql variance and standard deviation within timeframe

Tags: mysql, statistics, variance, calculus

Hello having a table like:

```
DateTime               Ip
2016-12-21 17:00:01 |  127.0.0.1 
2016-12-21 17:00:01 |  127.0.0.1 
2016-12-21 17:00:03 |  127.0.0.1 
2016-12-21 17:00:05 |  127.0.0.2 
2016-12-21 17:00:06 |  127.0.0.2 
2016-12-21 17:00:06 |  127.0.0.1 
2016-12-21 17:00:07 |  127.0.0.2 
2016-12-21 17:00:08 |  127.0.0.2 
2016-12-21 17:00:08 |  127.0.0.1 
2016-12-21 17:00:08 |  127.0.0.1
```

currently to calculate request per second of an ip in a certain period of time eg 5s I do:

```
SELECT Ip, total/diff_in_secs as Rps FROM (
SELECT Ip, count(*) as total, MAX(DateTime), MIN(DateTime), TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(DateTime), MAX(DateTime)) as diff_in_secs    
FROM requests WHERE DateTime >= '2016-12-21 17:00:01' AND DateTime <= '2016-12-21 17:00:05'
   GROUP BY Ip
   ) as base
   ORDER BY Rps Desc
```

I am trying to figure out a way to do variance and standard deviation of each ip during that period of time, from the rps any idea ? i am trying to apply the concepts in this answer with little success [Calculate average, variance and standard deviation of two numbers in two different rows/columns with sql / PHP on specific dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478948/calculate-average-variance-and-standard-deviation-of-two-numbers-in-two-differe)

Thank you

Comment: MySQL has built in singlepass aggregate functions for stats. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
select 
requests_per_sec.ip, 
avg(requests_per_sec.n) as Avg_Req_Per_Sec,
std(requests_per_sec.n) as Std_Req_Per_Sec
from
 (select ip, count(ip) as n, datetime 
  from requests 
  group by datetime, ip) requests_per_sec 
group by requests_per_sec.ip
```

To reduce the size of the inner select you can also count requests for instance every 5 seconds using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) div 5` like this

```
select 
requests_per_sec.ip, 
avg(requests_per_sec.n) as Avg_Req_Per_Sec,
std(requests_per_sec.n) as Std_Req_Per_Sec
from
 (select ip, count(ip) as n, datetime 
  from requests 
  group by UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) div 5, ip) requests_per_sec 
group by requests_per_sec.ip
```

Comment: thanks a lot i can work with that, i think is a good solution, for my use case I'll put put datetime >= last minute as well, also if there are gaps of data between seconds I guess avarage won't be accurate in an absolute time sense?

Comment: @davidear yes if you consider intervals of 5 secs you have an average of requests per 5 secs, to get an approximate average per second you'll have to divide by 5